# Angularjs displaying ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

Basically my angular code looks like this

```
    var myapp = angular.module("Demo",["ngRoute"])
            .config(function($routeProvider){
                $routeProvider                                                      
                    .when("/students",{
                        templateUrl : "templates/students.html",
                        controller : "grouplistcontroller"
                    })
            })              
            .controller("grouplistcontroller", function($scope,$http){                      
                $http.get("ajaxfunction.php?action=getlist")
                    .then(function(res) {   
                        var obj = JSON.stringify(res);
                        console.log(obj);
                        $scope.students = obj.data;
                    });                     
            });
```

The json data from server looks like this

```
"data":[
{
"sub_id":"1199",
"sub_group":"GT"
},
{
"sub_id":"727",
"sub_group":"GT"
},
{
"sub_id":"660",
"sub_group":"GT"
},
{
"sub_id":"614",
"sub_group":"GT"
}
],
"status":200,
"config":{
"method":"GET",
"transformRequest":[
null
],
"transformResponse":[
null
],
"url":"ajaxfunction.php?action=getlist",
"headers":{
"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"
}
},
"statusText":"OK"
```

I am trying to display the loop from the result in my front end, which isnt working

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="student in students">
        {{ student.sub_id }}
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Define *"isn't working"*

Comment: The isn't working would be redirecting to the ng-repeat or to the json data, trying to figure out where it is

Comment: Oh, you have a typo. It should be `$scope.students = res.data`, not `obj.data`. `obj` is your JSON string and it has no `data` property. See http://plnkr.co/edit/8KMvL0CX6Bry3oBNdHct?p=preview

Comment: why are you converting it to a string?  in that form you can't access to the properties of the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi You Don't have to convert JSON.stringify(obj), Simply Use as Object ... Use the Below Controller

```
.controller("grouplistcontroller", function($scope,$http){                      
                $http.get("ajaxfunction.php?action=getlist")
                    .then(function(res) {   


                        $scope.students = res.data;
                    });                     
            });
```

Answer (score -2):

I think controller for not getting the data from server.
COntroller not intended for that. you should use services for that see this code. I hope this might works for you.

```
<body ng-app="Demo">
  <div ng-controller="grouplistcontroller">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="student in students">
        {{ student.sub_id }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

Module:

```
   var myapp = angular.module("Demo", ["ngRoute"])
     .config(function($routeProvider) {
       $routeProvider
         .when("/students", {
           templateUrl: "templates/students.html",
           controller: "grouplistcontroller"
         })
     });
```

Controller:

```
myapp.controller("grouplistcontroller", ['$scope', 'SampleService', function($scope, SampleService) {
   function suuccessMethod(res) {

     $scope.students = res.data;
   }

   function errorMethod(err) {

   }


   SampleService.get().then(suuccessMethod, errorMethod);
 }]);
```

Services:

```
   myapp.factory('SampleService', function($http) {
     return {

       get: function() {
         return $http.get("ajaxfunction.php?action=getlist");
       }

     }

   });
```

Coming your issues: issue at this function:

```
function suuccessMethod(res) {

     $scope.students = res.data;
   }
```

Place this as above i hope it will works

Comment: *"you should use services for that"* <- `$http` **is** a service

Comment: Yes it is service sorry I didn't get your question?

Comment: Why create a service (`SampleService`) to just wrap another service (`$http`) without adding anything to it?

Comment: I don't have big reason for that but I think in our application can readable by doing this.
All server commuication call can be wrapped in the single service so that it readable for us

Comment: Debugging also easy I think. can't be?? If am wrong please correct me